# Doing math with lists

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate the cost each person will have to pay daily on a trip. I can get the prompts to work, but not the math. I have no idea on how to do the math with the lists. Anyone got any ideas?

Here is what I have so far:

```
def main():

    morepeople = True
    NumPPL = list()
    Days = list()
    Gas = list()
    Food = list ()
    Nopeople = 0
    
    while(morepeople):
        Numppl = (input('Enter the amount of people traveling: '))

        if(Numppl == Nopeople):
            morepeople = False
        else:
            NumPPL.append(Numppl)
            Days.append(input('Enter the amount of predicted days traveling: '))
            Gas.append(input('Enter gas cost per day: '))
            Food.append(input('Enter food cost per day: '))
            break
    Cost = sum(Gas) and sum(Food)/ sum(NumPPL)
    print('Everyones daily share is: ', Cost)
        
main()
```

Comment: While the distinction doesn't appear to matter in your situation, it is good to use the correct terminology because arrays are not the same as lists.

Comment: _"I have no idea on how to do the math"_: What math are you trying to do? What is the problem here? Please see [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953) -- you need to have a specific question, _"Anyone got any ideas?"_ is [too broad for Stack Overflow](/help/on-topic)

Comment: I see multiple problems with your code at a glance: 1. `Numppl` is a _string_ so it can never `== Nopeople`, which is an integer. 2. `input` always returns strings. You can't sum strings and expect a numeric result. 3. What do you mean to achieve with `and` in `sum(Gas) and sum(Food) / sum(NumPPL)`? 4. Why ask for number of people every time? Why not ask just once and loop that many times?

Comment: I now see my mistakes you pointed out. The result I was trying to get with the "sum(Gas) and sum(Food) / sum(NumPPL)" was to add the user input for food and gas prices and divide that total by the number of people that are on the trip.

Answer (score -1):

welcome to these boards.
This is a curious approach and interesting question.

Couple things to help you...
1> Input() passes a string regardless of the value actually input. You should convert it to an integer or float before using it in a mathematical operation.

2> As dea87 called out, aggregations on list objects require sum() or len() to get the total of values or count of entries, respectively.